# Start a new thread without making variables final

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, arraylist

Hello guys I want to place the following code in a new thread that is different from the ui thread but android studio gives an error that the variable needs to be declared final. when i declare the variable final it crashes my app. Please how can i start a new thread without declaring the variable final.

```
public void checkUpTaking(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) { //taken pawn: -1 = brown, 1 = white
        if (position > 10) { //if you'll try to take from the last row - array out of bounds
            if (position % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 4 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 - 9].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position - 9, position-4-rowImpact); //checking possible mandatory moves before clicking pawn
            }
            if ((position - 1) % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 5 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 - 11].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position - 11, position-5-rowImpact);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to achieve something like this without make my variable final

```
  public void checkUpTaking(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) { //taken pawn: -1 = brown, 1 = white
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (position > 10) { //if you'll try to take from the last row - array out of bounds
                    if (position % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 4 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                            playableTile[position - 1 - 9].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                        checkTreeNodes(position, position - 9, position-4-rowImpact); //checking possible mandatory moves before clicking pawn
                    }
                    if ((position - 1) % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 5 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                            playableTile[position - 1 - 11].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                        checkTreeNodes(position, position - 11, position-5-rowImpact);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: "without make my variable final" I can't see why you'd need to make them final anyway. Is there other code you're not showing where the parameters are reassigned?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a checkers game and there is an Anr error i am trying to solve that. so i am trying to reduce workdone on my main thread. My code is very lengthy and its body is limited on stackoverflow

Comment: But the code you've shown here [doesn't require `final`](https://ideone.com/fbgpTM). If there is other code in this method which reassigns these variables, the simple answer is to extract either the code you've shown or the code you've not into another method.

Comment: Why can't you declare the variables final? I'm not sure if android has a different rule than java. You can put final on method arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown here [doesn't require `final`](https://ideone.com/fbgpTM), at least when compiling in Java 8+, which allows anonymous classes to reference effectively-final variables.

The only reason you wouldn't be able to reference the parameters inside the anonymous class is if there is code which reassigns them (either inside or outside the anonymous class): without reassignment, the parameters would be considered *effectively final*.

If there is other code in this method which reassigns these variables, the simple answer is to extract either the code you've shown or the code you've not into another method:

```
public void checkUpTaking(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) {
  // The code creating the thread.

  restOfTheMethodBody(position, rowImpact, takenPawn);
}

private void restOfTheMethodBody(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) {
  // The code which needs to update position/rowImpact/takenPawn.
}
```

Or you can declare extra variables with the same values as the parameters, and reference these inside the thread:

```
int positionCopy = position;
// etc.
```

Or you can declare the `Runnable` with a named class, and give it a constructor and explicit fields:

```
class CheckUpTakingRunnable implements Runnable {
  private final int position;
  // etc.

  CheckUpTakingRunnable(int position /* etc */) {
    this.position = position;
  }

  // run() method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make position, rowImpact, or takenPawn final.
But you can't change it before your new Thread(new Runnable()..
If you have to it has to be final.. why? here is a detailed description: https://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/08/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class.html

To solve this you have some possibilities:

1. make a new final variable, and use this in your Runnable

   final int finalPosition = position;
2. put them in an array, and use for example params[0]  in your Runnable.
   I don't like this approach

   int[] params = new int[]{position, rowImpact, takenPawn};
3. create a wrapper object for your parameters

```java
    //as own class or even as inner class
    public class CheckupParameters
    {
        public CheckupParameters(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn)
        {
            this.position = position;
            this.rowImpact = rowImpact;
            this.takenPawn = takenPawn;
        }
        
        int position;
        int rowImpact;
        int takenPawn;
    }
    
    // in then before your Thread...
    CheckupParameters checkupParameters = new CheckupParameters(position, rowImpact,     takenPawn);
    
    // and in your Runnable you can access
    params.position
```

Comment: "In my opinion your code compiles" opinion shouldn't come into it: it compiles, or it doesn't :)

Comment: @AndyTurner thank yo for your advice. It compiles on my machine. But I'm not sure why. I can remember that former I often had to put variables final to be used in inner classes.
But now my IDE don't complains. Did this change in a more recent java version? not sure

Comment: You don't need to declare local variables explicitly final as of Java 8, which introduced the notion of being *effectively final*.